# Kindle soft key bar hovering

Tags: android, layout, toolbar, kindle

How do I stop the Kindle Soft Key Toolbar from hovering over my application. I would instead like the soft key bar to push my application to the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an option, at least not on the Kindle Fire HD, which I believe is the device you are referring to.

According to [the Amazon mobile app blog](http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2012/10/optimizing-for-soft-key-support-on-kindle-fire-hd.html), "you should be aware that the soft key toolbar and the drag handle appear over your content rather than resizing the drawable area."

Comment: Thanks, this is enough for me.